# SSRS Percentage not coming proper

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, percentage, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012

I am using the Pie chart and Showing the Percentage based on Group count. Most of the Time I am getting write Answer some time the total is coming 99 percent. like below example
I have Pie Chart its showing 35 ,32 and 32. I am not getting the  (35+32+32) 99 
i need out put like 36 32 32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is usually due to rounding the numbers in the chart display.

Your data is something like **35.4**, **32.4**, **32.2** but when they get rounded it seems to only add up to 99.

The way I usually handle this is to display one digit past the decimal point. Not a great fix but it did stop managers from asking why it didn't add up to 100%.

Comment: some time i used decimal point , in some case it shows 99.99 and 100.1. any other why to fixed this issue

Comment: Unfortunately, you're always going to have the potential for rounding issues whenever you have data that doesn't have round numbers that divide easily. Apparently Excel uses a formula to calculate percentages better than SSRS. Unfortunately, the genius execs at Microsoft (who never actually use their products) didn't feel this same functionality was needed in SSRS. http://sohu.io/questions/1118902/calculate-percentages-like-excel-pie-chart